# Spacy NER splitting the entity into two separate entities

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I am doing NER on the following text

```
print([(i.text, i.label_) for i in doc.ents])
```

My text looks like

```
ZS L-1 Cocoa & Burgers Ltd
-
2013 to 2017
```

I am getting the output

```
('ZS L-1', 'ORG'), ('Cocoa & Burgers Ltd', 'ORG'), ('2017', 'DATE')
```

How can i get the ORG name correctly as

```
('ZS L-1 Cocoa & Burgers Ltd', 'ORG')
```

Also it fails to recognise the 2013 as DATE entity. My spacy version is 2.0 and I am using this model - en_core_web_md-2.0.0. This generally happens when I am doing NER on the whole text. When I do NER on just the company name, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so adding answer here :

You have two solution:

Either you train your model as per your own data :

[Training spaCy’s Statistical Models](https://spacy.io/usage/training)

Second option try to download large model , You are using medium one this time :

[Available models : sm,md,lg](https://spacy.io/usage/models#available)

You can also compare the output of small , large model [here](https://spacy.io/models/comparison) :

Comment: this is the answer, you need to train on data that is representative of your domain as @netplay suggests.